# Alternative to GetX ever() method using Provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I want to move away from GetX, but ever() is a method I rely heavily upon. I wanted to switch to provider, but it doesn't seem like provider have a listener method like GetX does. Does Flutter or Provider have a built in method similar to this? Or other alternative packages? I know Flutter has a .addListener() method, but that is only used for animation and such, not on variable.

Comment: `addListener` can be called on any `Listenable`, so it can be `ValueListenable` for example, not only `Animation`

Comment: Thank you, but I realized my question is a bit inaccurate. Let me clarify, in GetX, you are able to add a listener one time only in the controller through the initstate. Can you do that with Provider? Or is there any other way.

Comment: so you want to use `Provider` or low level `Listenable` stuff?

Comment: Provider please if possible.

Comment: i am pretty sure you can have such "listeners" with `bloc` pattern, with `Provider` i am not so sure if you can do that: it only exposes builders that deal with UI widgets

Comment: I see. What happens if I were to use a combination of Listenable and provider together? Instead of using int, say I use ValueNotifier of int and include a NotifyListerner every time I update it. Would that be practical?

Comment: you mean to use [ChangeNotifierProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html)? and calling `addListener` on input `ChangeNotifier`?

Comment: I think so yes.